# How to validate a single property with VAB / Entity framework?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, enterprise-library

I'm using Entity Framework and all the entities inherits from BaseObject:

```
public class BaseObject : IDataErrorInfo
{
    private string _validationMessage;

    public BaseObject()
    { 
        _validationMessage = string.Empty;
    }

    public void Validate()
    {
        Validator validator = ValidationFactory.CreateValidator(GetType());

        var validationResults = validator.Validate(this);

        if (validationResults.Count > 0)
        {
            StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var validationResult in validationResults)
            {
                message.Append(validationResult.Message);
                message.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            }

            _validationMessage = message.ToString();
            //throw new ValidationException(message.ToString());
        }
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get 
        {
            _validationMessage = string.Empty;

            this.Validate();

            return _validationMessage;
        }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get 
        { 
            _validationMessage = string.Empty;

            this.Validate();

            return _validationMessage;
        }
    }
}
```

BaseObjects implements the IDataErrorInfo interface so I can use the ErrorProvider in combination with a bindingsource. The problem with this code is that when one property is invalid, all the other properties are invalid too. So my question is, how can I solve this? I am using the Validation Application Block and I don't know how I can validate a single property.

Answer (score 1):

@Tuzo: I think it is possible by using the [PropertyValidationFactory.GetPropertyValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff672198%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx) method.